# Making Southern style chicken in the oven

Tags: chicken

I've been trying to make southern style chicken in the oven. I firstly soak my chicken in buttermilk, I then dredge it in flour, leave to stand for half an hour to dry a bit. I then dredge it again in the seasoned flour again. I've tried a egg wash and missing the egg wash out.  I then place the chicken on a quality non stick roasting dish and spray it with a butter/oil cooking mist. Every time I make this, the batter sticks to the roasting dish leaving one side of the chicken with no batter. Any ideas what I'm not doing correctly?

I've tried parchment paper and it sticks like crazy. I'm delicate about removing it from the pan. Would using a nonstick spray help?

[image]

Comment: How are you lifting the chicken from the pan when finished? If you are using something like a fork stuck into the top, then the crust releases from the chiken easier than the pan. Try using a pancake spatula underneath to gently loosen the batter from the pan and lift out.

Answer (score 2):

Try raising the chicken above the roasting pan, with something like a grill grate or roasting rack. Having air flow to the bottom of the chicken pieces will help crisp up the batter on that surface, and the surface area of anything that can stick to your chicken will be limited as well. You will also want to use very high heat (~450F) when cooking, so that the batter will get to the proper texture.

Answer (score 2):

You can buy oven racks that allow cooking chicken pieces (or potatoes) with no tray contact points

[image]

I imagine you could easily make one out of some steel wire too. Or take a spare wire oven rack, and cut ever second or third wire at the edge, and bend it up?

Answer (score 1):

Did you put the roasting dish/pan on a low rack in the oven so that the bottom cook properly ?
The heat from the bottom will cook the batter and prevent it from sticking.

You can use parchment paper. Put the chicken on the paper instead on the roasting dish.

Answer (score 1):

You say you have tried an egg wash, but you don't say in what order.  This way works for me.  After the buttermilk, I dredge in seasoned flour, dip in just beaten egg with no added water, and then back in the seasoned flour. To avoid sticking, line your tray with parchment, or sometimes I put the chicken on a rack placed on the tray so the heat can circulate under the chicken.  If you use the rack, give it a spray, as well as your chicken. Don't forget the biscuits!